# Type 'Any' has no subscript members - NSMutableArray

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, type-erasure

We imported an outdated project, it prompted us to convert it to Swift 3. As individuals who are not highly knowledgeable in Swift, we are having difficulties fixing an error.

```
import Foundation

class CellDescriptorHelper {

let itemKey = "Items"
let isExpandableKey = "isExpandable"
let isExpandedKey = "isExpanded"
let isVisibleKey = "isVisible"
let titleKey = "title"
let locationKey = "location"
let descriptionKey = "description"
let imageURLKey = "imageURL"
let typeKey = "type"
let cellIdentifierKey = "cellIdentifier"
let additionalRowsKey = "additionalRows"

fileprivate var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!
fileprivate var cellsToDisplay: NSMutableArray!

func getCellDescriptors(_ type: String) -> NSMutableArray {
    
    loadCellDescriptors(type)
    return cellDescriptors;
}

func loadCellDescriptors(_ type: String) {
    
    cellDescriptors = PlistManager.sharedInstance.getValueForKey(itemKey)! as! NSMutableArray
    
    for i in 0..<(cellDescriptors[0] as AnyObject).count-1 {
        
        let cellType = cellDescriptors[0][i][typeKey] as! String //creates error
        if(cellType != type) {
            cellDescriptors[0][i].setValue(false, forKey:  isVisibleKey) //creates error
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question like a text, not an image.

Comment: @user28434 hello, I edited the post.

Comment: @Honey - why did you add the Objective-C tag to a question about Swift code?

Comment: @rmaddy because of `NSMutableArray`. Is that wrong? If anyone in future wants to do some casting that's related to Objective-C stuff they can find this answer easier...

Comment: @Honey Yes, that's wrong. This question is 100% Swift. `NSMutableArray` can be used in Swift. It's existence in the Swift code doesn't mean the Objective-C tag is suddenly relevant.

Comment: @rmaddy I could be wrong but let's agree to disagree. I won't make any edits though.

Comment: @Honey Tags represent what a question is about. This question is in no way about the Objective-C programming language. There's not one single line of Objective-C code in the question. The question does not ask about any features of the Objective-C programming language. No one knowledgeable in Objective-C (if they don't also know Swift) would be able to answer this question. You seem to think the existence of `NSMutableArray` in the code suddenly makes the Objective-C tag relevant. It's a Foundation class with multiple language bindings. Same can be said for UIView and many other classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the type of the object that is in your array is ambiguous to the compiler.

This is due to the fact that `NSArray`s aren't typed concretely.
`NSArray` is basically the Objective-C bridge of `Array<Any>` or `[Any]`.

Let me walk you through your code...

`let cellType = cellDescriptors[0][i][typeKey] as! String`

The compiler knows that `cellDescriptors` is an `NSArray` as it is declared as one above. `NSArray`s can be subscripted to get the value at a given index, as you are doing with `cellDescriptors[0]`. The value this gives is of type `Any`, as explained above, so when you try and subscript it again with `cellDescriptors[0][i]`, you are getting your error. As it happens, you can likely cast that `Any` object to an array, then you'll be able to perform the subscript, like so:

`if let newArr = (cellDescriptors[0] as? [Any])[i] { }`

However, this really isn't a nice approach and you end up dealing with a load of nasty optionals.

A better approach would be to concrete your declaration of `cellDescriptors`. I don't know how your type structure lies, but by the looks of things, it's an array of arrays of dictionaries (yuck). So in a raw form, your declaration should be `var cellDescriptors = [[[AnyHashable:Any]]]()` in order to subscript as you are now.

This said, the code you have in place is messy and I would consider changing the way you model your objects to make it more usable.

Comment: This line `var cellDescriptors = [[[:]]]` gives me an error: `cannot call value of non-function type '[Array<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>]'` removing the `()` fixes it or *perhaps* doing something like `[[[Any:cellDesciptors]]]()` is what you originally meant?

Comment: Try `var cellDescriptors = [[[String : String]]]()`.  Explicit types should work.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I was getting mixed up with assignment and declaration syntax.

Comment: Neither of these solutions work.  If Swift is so great why does a simple declaration in Obj C have to be so complicated ?  NSMutableArray.  Really better to convert this project to Obj C Swift3 created 150 errors in 600 lines of code. Replace Default with default?  Really  Wrapping, unwrapping

Answer (score 3):

These lines have two problems:

```
fileprivate var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!
fileprivate var cellsToDisplay: NSMutableArray!
```

First, they're `!` types (implicitly unwrapped optional or IUOs). They should never have been `!` types, but in Swift 3 these work differently than they did in Swift 2, and that is likely breaking you. Get rid of the `!` and assign these to an empty array to start. There are very few places that `!` types are still useful (`@IBOutlet` is one of the last hold outs where `!` types can be appropriate, at least as a matter of opinion.)

The other problem is that `NSMutableArray` is a sloppy type, and it creates a ton of headaches in Swift. It should only be used in very rare cases where a bridge to Objective-C requires it (this is exceedingly rare for `NSMutableArray`).

Convert `cellDescriptors` and `cellsToDisplay` to an appropriate `Array` type rather than `NSMutableArray`. "Appropriate" means "an array of whatever is actually in it." That means `[Any]` is not an appropriate type. If `cellsToDisplay` contains a bunch of `Cell` objects, then it should be `[Cell]`.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray really doesn't tell much... Avoid force unwrapping and try to think of which types should the array be first. At first the array should have inside next array according to subscripting... so try to OverType it instead of NSMutableArray to type : [[Any]] but this option is really not safe at all!

Please provide more information about what the itemKey value should be... but overally my best tip is this:

```
func loadCellDescriptors(_ type: String) {

    guard let cellDescriptors =  PlistManager.sharedInstance.getValueForKey(itemKey)? as? [[String: Any]], let firstDescriptor = cellDescriptors[0]
else { return } 


 for someKeyInDict in 0..<cellDescriptor.count{

       if let cellType = cellDescriptor[i][typeKey] as? String{
        if(cellType != type) {
            cellDescriptors[0][i].setValue(false, forKey: isVisibleKey)
        }
      }
    }
```

This won't on 100% work, but will get you closer, I just tip that the value you are seraching is dictionary...

Comment: Could you provide a code to elaborate what you are trying to explain?

Comment: Thank you very much